# Navigation button doesn't show up

Tags: ios, swift, cocoa-touch, uiviewcontroller, uibarbuttonitem

I am trying to display a button in the iOS toolbar, in theory it's pretty simple and this should work:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
        let refresh = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: .Refresh, target: self, action: "refreshTapped")
        navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = refresh
        navigationController?.toolbarHidden = false
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }
}
```

Still it does not. The button doesn't show up. I tried rebooting the simulator, creating project from the scratch, etc. So I guess it's a flaw in the way my Swift-beginner mind approaches the problem, but I simply don't see it.

Comment: Is your view wrapped inside a UINavigationController?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to your Storyboar, select the View Controller, then in Xcode top bar select Editor -> Embed in -> Navigation Controller.

In your code, when you are saying

```
navigationController?.toolbarHidden = false
```

If you CMD + click on navigationController? you will read a comment next to the variable: "If this view controller has been pushed onto a navigation controller, return it."

So only works if your view has been pushed onto a navigation controller.

Comment: Perfect, thank you! I just realised that in previous projects I was doing exactly this :)